# regular expression to grab quoted text in PHP code

Tags: php, regex

I have the following line:

```
<?php echo $this->__("mytext");?>somesometext")moretext
```

and I need a regular expression to grab 'mytext'. The best I could come up with is:

```
/\$this->__\([\'"](.*)[\'"]\)/
```

but in this case it returns:

```
mytext");?>somesometext
```

Can anyone get this to work?

Comment: What can `mytext` be? Can it contain escaped double quotes like this: `<?php echo $this->__("my \" text");?>somesometext")moretext`?

Comment: @Bart Yes, it can have anything you could possibly pass to a function as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/\$this->__\([\'"](.*?)[\'"]\)/
```

The `?` makes the `*` quantifier ungreedy.

Comment: Both this and Stefan's answers are correct. Picked the one that needed the rep the most.

Answer (score 3):

Better use PHP’s ability to parse its own code with [`token_get_all`](http://php.net/token_get_all), step through the tokens and stop at the first [`T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING` token](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php).

Comment: Even though impractical for my application, +1 for leveraging PHP tokenizer's power.

Answer (score 2):

```
/\$this->__\([\'"](.*?)[\'"]\)/
```

should work. The `?` switches the match-mode to *ungreedy*.